# Loads of extra space at bottom of classes in Visual Studio 2008 C# Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The scrollbar scrolls way past the end of my class. Is there any way to adjust this? Is it just the VS convention? I can't delete the space, so it isn't carriage returns.

The reason I don't like this is that I keep accidentally scrolling past the end of my class!

I'd especially like to hear from people who actually have Visual Studio 2008 installed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have extra newlines (the cr/lfs Jim Anderson was talking about) in which case you can just select all the blank lines and hit delete to get rid of the extra space.  The other possibility is that what you think is blank space is just the IDE letting you scroll down one page past the end of the file (until the last line of the file is at the very top of the screen).  This is to let you scroll to the bottom of the file and start typing without causing the screen to scroll every time you start a new line.

Edit:
A quick glance at the other editors on my computer shows that this sort of thing is common - CodeWright will let you keep scrolling down as far as you want (pages and pages past the end of text) - although it does show the scroll bar as being all the way to the bottom when the bottom of the file is in the middle of the screen of text.

Even basic tools like Query Analyzer have this.

Comment: yes it is. why does it do that? I've never seen it in any other app

Comment: It's to make life easier on you when you're adding new stuff to the end of the file.  It's a pretty common feature in GUI text editors.

Comment: I'm curious where the visceral hatred of the extra space comes from?

Comment: I keep accidentally scrolling past the end of my class!

Comment: I see your point.  If you just want to get to the end of the file, try <ctrl-end>. It will zip the cursor to the end of the file leaving the last full page of code visible in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature (no, not a bug relabeled a "feature").

Answer (score 0):

Reboot? No seriously, more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have CR/LFs you you need to delete.